# Ajuda montar select

Tags: sql

*Tabela Produto*

```
TB_PRODUTO:
CODIGO PRODUTO  ST_PRODUTO DT_ENTRADA
 1100  NOTEBOOK    0       20/05/2019
 1200  NOTEBOOK    1       21/05/2019
 1300  NOTEBOOK    2       22/05/2019
 1400  NOTEBOOK    0       23/05/2019
 1500  NOTEBOOK    2       24/05/2019
 1600  NOTEBOOK    3       25/05/2019
```

Boa noite, gostaria de fazer um select na tabela produto acima para me retornar 
    os notebooks com `ST_PRODUTO` diferente `0`, porém se a data de entrada for maior que 
    `'21/05/2019'` quero que retorne o `ST_PRODUTO 0` que são depois dessa data.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é:

```
Select *
From TB_PRODUTO
WHERE (DT_ENTRADA >= '2019-05-21' AND ST_PRODUTO = 0)
OR (DT_ENTRADA < '2019-05-21' AND ST_PRODUTO <> 0)
```